# How to format a list which has two elements

Tags: python

```
list = [(a, 59.34), (t, 56.54), (d, 34.74), (u, 5.89)]
```

The list is descending order of the number(the second element)
I would like to format them like below.

a: 59.34

t: 56.54

d: 34.74

u: 5.89

```
details = []
    for item in list:
name = item[0]
num = item[2]
details.append(f"{name}: {num:.2f}")
```

Comment: Aside from the indentation. If the first element is `0` then the second element would be... `1` no?

Comment: I think you should change list to dict, which will be perfect for your list. I think*

Comment: It looks like you have a solution (except for the error noted above); what is the problem exactly?

Comment: How can I change the list to a dict??

Comment: I don't know how to format the list to my ideal comment.

Comment: Please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), then.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [('a', 59.34), ('t', 56.54), ('d', 34.74), ('u', 5.89)]

details = [f"{x[0]}: {x[1]:.2f}" for x in lst]
print(*details, sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
a: 59.34
t: 56.54
d: 34.74
u: 5.89
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to convert the list to a dictionary.  You can use dictionary comprehension to iterate through the list and convert the tuple(key, value) into key: value

```
list1 = [('a', 59.34), ('t', 56.54), ('d', 34.74), ('u', 5.89)]

dict_from_list = {key: val for (key, val) in list1}

print(dict_from_list)
# {'a': 59.34, 't': 56.54, 'd': 34.74, 'u': 5.89}
```

Answer (score 0):

lst = [('a', 59.34), ('t', 56.54), ('d', 34.74), ('u', 5.89)]
list_comp = [f"{i[0]}: {i[-1]}" for i in lst]
print(list_comp)

(Ans)
['a: 59.34', 't: 56.54', 'd: 34.74', 'u: 5.89']

(Or )

for j in lst:
print(f"{j[0]}: {j[-1]}")

(Ans)
a: 59.34
t: 56.54
d: 34.74
u: 5.89

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary comprehension as your list already has elements as pairs therefore you have to just do the following:

```py
items = [('a', 59.34), ('t', 56.54), ('d', 34.74), ('u', 5.89)]    # try not to use the built-in method names or keywords as variable names
details = {k:v for k,v in items}    # it uses the first element of the tuple as key and seocnd as a value
print(details)
```

Would output:

```py
{'a': 59.34, 't': 56.54, 'd': 34.74, 'u': 5.89}
```

You could also use a loop:

```py
items = [('a', 59.34), ('t', 56.54), ('d', 34.74), ('u', 5.89)]
details = {}
for i in items:
    details[i[0]] = i[1]

print(details)
```

Would result in:

```py
{'a': 59.34, 't': 56.54, 'd': 34.74, 'u': 5.89}
```